# Angular bootstrap prepends css html page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 1.3.2 in an angular web application. I'm using only the js library, not the css as I'm providing my own styles to the app. But in the resulting web application there are a few  elements in the  with css data which I did not insert.

I checked the bootstrap library and just at the end there are some lines similar to this.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.carousel').run(function() {
  !angular.$$csp().noInlineStyle && !angular.$$uibCarouselCss && angular.element(document).find('head').prepend('<style type="text/css">.ng-animate.item:not(.left):not(.right){-webkit-transition:0s ease-in-out left;transition:0s ease-in-out left}</style>');
  angular.$$uibCarouselCss = true;
});
```

As you can see, this is inserting some css in my web page. I can just comment these lines, but I wonder, why is bootstrap doing something like this? is this some 'core' css for the component which should not be removed?

I commented those lines and everything seems to be working fine.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3904

Comment: could you please elaborate? I vaguely understand that $$csp is used as a security measure, but I'm not sure why the css needs to be inyected this way. If I comment only the `angular.element(document)...`part my datepicker does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Those styles are there to support certain behaviors in the directives, here is a [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.css) to the carousel css in source.  You should leave those styles in your page.